# Bad operand : não aceita contas nem comparações!

Tags: java

Estou tendado resolver o seguinte problema:
*João Papo-de-Pescador, homem de bem, comprou um microcomputador
para controlar o rendimento diário de seu trabalho. Toda vez que ele
traz um peso de peixes maior que o estabelecido pelo regulamento de
pesca do estado de São Paulo (50 quilos) deve pagar uma multa de R$
4,00 por quilo excedente. João precisa que você faça um programa que
leia a variável peso (peso de peixes) e calcule o excesso. Gravar na
variável excesso a quantidade de quilos além do limite e na variável
multa o valor da multa que João deverá pagar. Imprima os dados do
programa com as mensagens adequadas.*

Mas o compilador não esta aceitando minhas comparações e somas, onde estou errando?

```
package papodepescador;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class PapoDePescador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        peso.quanto();

    }
 class peso {
    private static void quanto(){
        System.out.println("Quantos quilos de peixes temos hoje João? ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean quilo = sc.nextBoolean();
        if(quilo <= 50){
           System.out.println("A quantidade " + quilo+"Kg de peixes esta dentro do"
                    + " limite de peso do regulamento do estado de São Paulo. Muito bem João!");

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Que pena João!\n Infelismente você esta com " + excesso(quilo) 
                    + "Kg acima do limite.\n E terá que pagar uma multa de R$" + multa.valor(quilo)+ ".");
        }
    }
    public static boolean excesso(boolean quilo){
         return quilo / 50.00;
        }

    }
 public class multa {


    public static boolean valor(boolean quilo){
          boolean aux;
          aux = 50.00 / quilo * 4.00;
          return aux;

        }
    }

}
```

os erros bad operand ocorrem nas linhas:

```
if(quilo <= 50){


return quilo / 50.00;
```

e o flip operands:

```
aux = 50.00 / quilo * 4.00;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando realizar divisões e usar o operador relacional `<=` entre um `boolean` (verdadeiro ou falso) e um número nas variáveis `quilo` e `aux`.

Substitua o tipo `boolean` por `int`, `float` ou `double` nas declarações das variáveis e no tipo de retorno das funções `excesso` e `valor`

```java
int quilo = sc.nextInt(); 
// sc.nextFloat(); caso quilo for float
// sc.nextDouble(); caso quilo for double
```

```java
public static int excesso(int quilo){
    return quilo / 50.00;
}
```

```java
public static int valor(int quilo){
    int aux;
    aux = 50.00 / quilo * 4.00;
    int aux;
}
```

Comment: Claro, muito obrigado,